# Regex with exactly one block of 0s with even length

Tags: regex

The alphabet is `{0, 1}`.

A "block of 0s" means a substring of 0s not contained in a longer substring of 0s.

I came up with: `(0(00)*)* 1* 00(00)* 1* (0(00)*)*`

Is it correct?

Comment: An example would be better.

Answer (score 1):

For exactly one block of zeros of even length with a vocab of 1 and 0:

```
^1*(00)+1*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '(?<=^|1)(00)+(?=1|$)' input
```

- `(00)+`   -- even number of zeros
- `(?<=  ^ | 1 )` -- before (left context): a "`1`" or the start of the string
- `(?= 1 | $ )`  -- after (right context): a "`1`" or the end of the string
- `grep -oP` -- regexp can be used in many different ways; `-P` -- to include Perl extensions ; `grep -o` -- print  only  the  matched parts

with input

```
000
0000
00001
11100110000001
```

outputs

```
0000
0000
00
000000
```

Comment: please elaborate on the solution

Comment: @EliranMalka OK. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 (\b(00){1,})(?!0)
```

also I tried your solution and it didn't work